# Php add input field values in database

Tags: php, database, input, int, addition

What the best way to add values of input files and save them later on in the database.

My input fields look like these:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="10">
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="100">
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1000">
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="10000">
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="100000">
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1000000">
```

So if I check the first field and send the database saves 1 and if I check the first 3 the database should save 111(1+10+100) and so on...

Edit:

So I tried out your suggestion.
Printing out the array gives this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "test" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "10"
    2 => "100"
  ]
]
```

But if I array_sum that and print out the value I get a 0.

Comment: When you submit your form you can do a foreach loop and just do something like `foreach($test as $t) $adding += (int)$t`

Comment: Even better: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: @KeithTyler I didn't know about this function. Thanks!

Comment: @KeithTyler Didn't know about that too, thank you ! :)

Comment: Half of PHP's strength is in its array functions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sum = 0;
if(isset($_POST['test']) && is_array($_POST['test'])){
    $sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $_POST['test']));
}
```